# Googlemap Geocoding legal constraint

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was reading up the legal stuffs about Google Map and came across a post which pointed out this regulation:

*10.12 use or display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation, the Street View API Documentation, or through written permission from Google (for example, you must not use geocodes obtained through the Service except in conjunction with a Google map, but the Street View API Documentation explicitly permits you to display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map); or...*

However, I also bump into this very nice tutorial on displaying addresses that is within a specific radius of a targeted location:

http://stefanzvonar.com/2012/06/30/setting-up-google-maps-for-asp-net-and-sql-server-with-google-maps-api-v3/

In this tutorial, the database actually stores the Lat Long of an address which is crucial for this feature to work. Presumably, these Lat Long information may also be derived from the help of Google Map. In such scenario, is there a violation occurring? I am not sure if it relates to the regulation state above.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a grey area. You are not allowed to store actual data obtained from Google 
[2. Restrictions on Use](http://maps.google.com/help/terms_maps.html)

But it is suggested that if the results of geocoding is displayed on a map and the marker moved to the exact location the resulting coordinates are yours to store (I am not a lawyer).

The other option is to obtain to obtain the coordinates from another source eg [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/)